# How to organize search architecture on large amount of data about 10 million in .net

Tags: .net, architecture, search-engine

I have a table, which store about 10 million records(items), each record have itemtype(it's a reference key to table types). On my site i have a search functionality which based on fulltext search, it was ok, but a few days ago my customer want to show on the site not only all items but the itemtypes too.

I try to do two parallel request to different servers(one to repl server and one to main):

-- first request - group items by itemtypeid(with using fulltext search) and return list of itemtypeid

--second request - search keywords in database(fulltext search)

on the web server i aggregate results from these requests and push it to the web browser.
Problem: first request run not so fast as i want :) (it's very slow) and after six(eight) month there will be more than 11 million items, so, first request will be slower and slower.

Show me, please, the right way.

Comment: When you talk about "full text search" what do you mean?

1) A query with a "like '%searchdata%" clause
2) A proper full text search engine like Lucene or SQL Server full text search

Please detail

Comment: yes i mean sql server full text search, i have created indexing view.

Answer (score 1):

Except what was said by @sonyc you should also take into account:

1. **The order in which tables should be joined.**   How does a database
   management system carry out a join
   between the Item and ItemType
   tables? It is useful to have a bit
   of an idea of what may happen, so
   you can make some informed decisions
   about adding indexes.

   One approach to joining tables is
   called nested loops. This means that
   you scan down the rows in one table,
   and for each row, you look through
   all the rows in the other table to
   find matches for the join condition.

   Obviously, which table is in the
   outside loop will make a difference.
   If we start scanning the ItemType
   table, we need to be able to quickly
   find the row with the matching
   ItemID in the Item table. If we
   start by choosing rows in the Item
   table, we need to quickly find the
   matching ItemID in the ItemType
   table. Because there will always be
   an index on the primary key ItemID
   in the Item table, the first option
   will always be quite efficient.
2. **Which fields should be indexed**.

   Another approach to doing a join is
   to first sort both tables by the
   join field. It is then very easy to
   find matching rows. This is called a
   merge join. Sorting each table is an
   expensive operation. However, if the
   tables are already sorted (they both
   have a clustered index on the join
   field ItemID), then this merging
   operation is very efficient.

We looked at a couple ways the database system could carry out
a join: with nested loops or with a sort and merge. Which one will occur? Fortunately, we
don’t have to worry about this, as good relational database products have a query optimizer
to figure out the most efficient way.

So, for futher query optimisation we should carry out using Query Optimizer. The query optimizer will take into account a number of things, such as which indexes are
present, the number of rows in the tables, the length of the rows, and which fields are
required in the output. An optimizer will look at all the possible steps for completing the
task and assign time costs to each. It then comes up with the most efficient plan.

You can also use query plan analysis tools to investigate the effect of adding indexes to
your tables. The index can speeds up your query significantly, especially when your tables get bigger.Indexes are usually automatically added for primary key fields. Indexes on fields
that you want to order by or use in a select condition can also be useful. It is always worth
checking the usefulness of adding an index to foreign key fields, as these are often used in
join conditions.
However, indexes come at a cost because they need to be updated every time a row in
the table is added, deleted, or altered. This can slow some updating operations while speeding
some retrieval operations. You need to decide how important the various efficiencies are
for your particular situation.

Comment: Thanks for you response. The first point in your comment(when you describe joining mechanism). Here is my own point: If i have index on itemtypeid in table items(non clustered, because clustered is itemid aka primary key) and i have a clustered index on itemtypeid (primary key), i think that increase in productivity will be scanty or no growth at all, because different between clustered and not clustered is only how their stored on the disk. But i will try this tommorow :), because my opinion based is only my opinion )

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first problem what about a key value lookup. The key will be your itemtypeid and the value will be a bag or list of items. I am not exactly sure how full text search plays into this. If you are resolving free text to a itemtypeid you might want to consider using something like Lucene.net. This will give you a great deal more control over index layout.

Something like this approach should give you response times of just a few milliseconds assuming you are holding everything in RAM. If you are looking for an off the shelf solution something like memcached or Velocity might be useful to you.

For your second request I would just use a lucene index to figure out what to get out of the database. Your database key layout can then be simple with just effectively key lookups. You should be able to get all this in less than 100ms regardless of datasize with a horizontal partitioning scheme.

Comment: This project use memcached, but i haven't enough ram to use memcached with whole type of data, i use memcache only for hottest(critical) data. About lucene: i don't understand how lucene could help in my aggregation function. Could you explain more detail please

Comment: Lucene would be used instead of SQL Full Text Search. You can build compact indexes with it and precisely control the fields in the index and how they are created. Its not aggregation really. It would give you a list of results sorted by a relevance algorithm.

Comment: I thought about it. Sql full text do his work good, the problem is aggregation. If i will use lucene.net i should analyze whole list of items and create list of itemtypeid. i don't think that it will be more quickly than using sql server. I do not have enough time to try realize this on mongodb :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have two tables: Item and ItemType. Each record in table Item has a foreign key to the table ItemType. You want to search for records in the table Item, and display both the Item and the ItemType in the result list.

If this is correct, just use a [JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014.aspx) clause in your initial request.

Comment: i forgot to write, that i used paging in my web site and i can't load all items. I am using row_number for paging functionality. Let assume that in the first 20 records i found five types, but on the page with number 10 i would have found more types, so the join does not solution for me